# Link a matrix to dataframe to multiply by matrix values

Tags: r

I have a small matrix that I would like to use to multiply a very large dataframe.

dataframe:

| Week | Category | Brand | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | Category1 | A | 100 |
| 202001 | Category2 | B | 105 |
| 202001 | Category3 | B | 101 |
| 202002 | Category1 | B | 103 |
| 202002 | Category2 | A | 111 |
| 202002 | Category3 | B | 107 |
| 202003 | Category1 | B | 106 |
| 202003 | Category2 | A | 113 |
| 202003 | Category3 | A | 109 |

matrix:

| Week | Brand A | Brand B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | 1.05% | 0.99% |
| 202002 | 1.07% | 1.02% |
| 202003 | 0.97% | 1.03% |

I would like to link these so that when week 202001 and Brand A, the value in Qty is multiplied by 1.05%
This data set is 10million+ lines so I can't do it manually.

Comment: Could you please use `dput()` to share your sample data? At least the matrix? Spaces in column names make it hard to import, and the class will be important as we'll need to remove the percent signs, convert to data frame and such. If you share `dput(your_matrix[1:3, ])` we'll have a copy/pasteable version of the object with all the correct class information.

Comment: Can't you merge the two after restructuring the matrix a bit? Create a single "Brand" column in the matrix (A or B) and a "value" column with 1.05 etc. (omit % sign of course), and turn it into a data frame. Then use `merge` or a similar function e.g., `df <- mege(df1, df2, by = c('Week', 'Brand'))` and finally, adjust Qty, e.g., `df$Qty <- df$value * df$Qty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two datasets and then multiply.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Week, names_to = "Brand", names_prefix = "Brand") %>% 
  mutate(value = parse_number(value)) %>% 
  right_join(dat) %>% 
  mutate(newQty = value * Qty)

# A tibble: 9 x 6
    Week Brand value Category    Qty newQty
   <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <int>  <dbl>
1 202001 A      1.05 Category1   100   105 
2 202001 B      0.99 Category2   105   104.
3 202001 B      0.99 Category3   101   100.
4 202002 A      1.07 Category2   111   119.
5 202002 B      1.02 Category1   103   105.
6 202002 B      1.02 Category3   107   109.
7 202003 A      0.97 Category2   113   110.
8 202003 A      0.97 Category3   109   106.
9 202003 B      1.03 Category1   106   109.
```

---

data

```r
mat <- read.table(header = T, text = "Week  BrandA  BrandB
202001  1.05%   0.99%
202002  1.07%   1.02%
202003  0.97%   1.03%")

dat <- read.table(header = T, text = "Week  Category    Brand   Qty
202001  Category1   A   100
202001  Category2   B   105
202001  Category3   B   101
202002  Category1   B   103
202002  Category2   A   111
202002  Category3   B   107
202003  Category1   B   106
202003  Category2   A   113
202003  Category3   A   109")
```